# No action is/- required on your side

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis

I received an email from my university that the following sentence was part of it:

> We confirmed everything, **no action required** on your part.

Looking up in the LDOCE dictionary, I think the correct sentence must be "**no action *is* required**" according to the two meanings there. Can anyone confirm me?

PS: I would be grateful if you could point me to the grammatical errors in the question if you spot any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an implied verb here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336293/is-there-an-implied-verb-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, but most people would accept the grammatically incorrect version.
A comma is not the right punctuation and for the sentence to be more nearly correct it would have to be put in parenthesis-still, is, as you point out would be needed to make it totally correct.